# Thymeleaf not loading content when I add validation in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, validation, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

## Intro:

My app works in the general sense. All as I want. But when I set up validation (and it does work), it won't load all my hidden content. I moved it all to its own page, and it still did not work. So I am asking here with my original set up. I understand it is messy, but I will clean it up once I figure this out.

I can't find anything related to my problem, which makes me think, the way that I am doing it might not be the best approach. So pointers are more than welcome.

## Problem:

Adding Validation to my forms breaks my Thymeleaf template. Unable to hide and unhide elements. It looks stuck. But on the terminal, the program does run fine.

## My controller

(it's big... I still need to learn how to break it in smaller chunks.)

```java
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"guess", "word", "result", "level", "attempt", "message", "credits", "name", "gameScore"})
public class GameController {

    private static final String WORD_TO_GUESS_CONSTANT = "WORD_TO_GUESS";
    private static final String GUESSED_WORD_CONSTANT = "GUESSED_WORD";
    private static final String RESULT_CONSTANT = "RESULT_WORD";
    private static final String ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT = "ATTEMPTS";
    private static final String TOTAL_ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT = "TOTAL_ATTEMPTS";
    private static final String MESSAGE_CONSTANT = "MESSAGE";
    private static final String CREDITS_CONSTANT = "CREDITS";
    private static final String SELECTED_LEVEL_CONSTANT = "SELECTED_LEVEL";
    private static final String NAME_CONSTANT = "NAME";
    private static final String GAME_SCORE_CONSTANT = "GAME_SCORE";
    private static final String SCORE_MULTIPLIER_CONSTANT = "SCORE_MULTIPLIER";

    @Autowired
    private RandomWordService randomWord;
    @Autowired
    private WordCheckService checkGuess;
    @Autowired
    private IsWordCorrectService isWordCorrectService;
    @Autowired
    private ScoreSavingService scoreSavingService;

    @ModelAttribute("gameDto")
    public GameDTO guessDTOForm() {
        return new GameDTO();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("score")
    public Score score() {
        return new Score();
    }

//   GAME METHODS

    @GetMapping(value = "/index")
    public String home(Model model,
                       final HttpServletRequest request,
                       final HttpSession session,
                       GameDTO gameDTO,
                       Score score) {
        
        model.addAttribute("name", session.getAttribute(NAME_CONSTANT));
        model.addAttribute("levelSelected", session.getAttribute(SELECTED_LEVEL_CONSTANT));
        model.addAttribute("attempt", session.getAttribute(ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT));
        model.addAttribute("credits", session.getAttribute(CREDITS_CONSTANT));
        model.addAttribute("attemptStart", session.getAttribute(TOTAL_ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT));
        model.addAttribute("guess", session.getAttribute(GUESSED_WORD_CONSTANT));
        model.addAttribute("result", session.getAttribute(RESULT_CONSTANT));
        model.addAttribute("message", session.getAttribute(MESSAGE_CONSTANT));
        model.addAttribute("gameScore", session.getAttribute(GAME_SCORE_CONSTANT));

        model.addAttribute("lvlName", Level.values());

        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/loadgame")
    public String loadWord(
            final HttpSession session, final HttpServletRequest request,
            @ModelAttribute("score") Score score,
            @Valid GameDTO gameDTO, BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model
    ) throws IOException {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("lvlName", Level.values());

            model.addAttribute("name", session.getAttribute(NAME_CONSTANT));
            model.addAttribute("levelSelected", session.getAttribute(SELECTED_LEVEL_CONSTANT));
            model.addAttribute("attempt", session.getAttribute(ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT));
            model.addAttribute("credits", session.getAttribute(CREDITS_CONSTANT));
            model.addAttribute("attemptStart", session.getAttribute(TOTAL_ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT));

            model.addAttribute("guess", session.getAttribute(GUESSED_WORD_CONSTANT));
            model.addAttribute("result", session.getAttribute(RESULT_CONSTANT));

            model.addAttribute("message", session.getAttribute(MESSAGE_CONSTANT));
            model.addAttribute("gameScore", session.getAttribute(GAME_SCORE_CONSTANT));

            return "index";
        }

        //  NEW GAME

        String word = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(WORD_TO_GUESS_CONSTANT);

        if (word == null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(NAME_CONSTANT, gameDTO.getPlayerName());
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT, gameDTO.getLvlName().getAttempts());
            request.getSession().setAttribute(WORD_TO_GUESS_CONSTANT, randomWord.selectRandomWord());
            request.getSession().setAttribute(CREDITS_CONSTANT, gameDTO.getCredit());
            request.getSession().setAttribute(SELECTED_LEVEL_CONSTANT, gameDTO.getLvlName().getLvlName());
            request.getSession().setAttribute(TOTAL_ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT, gameDTO.getLvlName().getAttempts());
            request.getSession().setAttribute(GAME_SCORE_CONSTANT, gameDTO.getScore());
            request.getSession().setAttribute(SCORE_MULTIPLIER_CONSTANT, gameDTO.getLvlName().getMultiplier());
            gameDTO.setWord((String) session.getAttribute(WORD_TO_GUESS_CONSTANT));
        }
        model.addAttribute("message", "");


        return "redirect:/index";
    }


    @PostMapping(value = "/guess")
    public String guessWord(
            final HttpSession session,
            final HttpServletRequest request,
            @ModelAttribute("score") Score score,
            @Valid GameDTO gameDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) throws IOException {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "index";
        }

        // variables
        int attempts = (int) session.getAttribute(ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT);
        int credits = (int) session.getAttribute(CREDITS_CONSTANT);
        int startAttempts = (int) session.getAttribute(TOTAL_ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT);
        String name = (String) session.getAttribute(NAME_CONSTANT);
        // check word
        String wordToGuess = (String) session.getAttribute(WORD_TO_GUESS_CONSTANT);
        String guess = gameDTO.getGuess();
        String result = checkGuess.resultWord(wordToGuess, guess);
        String lvl = (String) session.getAttribute(SELECTED_LEVEL_CONSTANT);
        // adjust score according to result
        boolean wordIsCorrect = isWordCorrectService.isTheWordCorrect(result, wordToGuess);
        int gameScore = (int) session.getAttribute(GAME_SCORE_CONSTANT);
        int scoreMultiplier = (int) request.getSession().getAttribute(SCORE_MULTIPLIER_CONSTANT);
        int wrongWord = gameDTO.getWrongWord();
        int initialScore = gameDTO.getStartScore();
        int finalScorePerWord = initialScore * scoreMultiplier;

        //   GAME LOGIC

        if (!wordIsCorrect) {
            String message = "";

            message = "Wrong! Try again!";
            request.getSession().setAttribute(MESSAGE_CONSTANT, message);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT, --attempts);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(GAME_SCORE_CONSTANT, gameScore - wrongWord);
            log(GameController.class, "Updated score: " + session.getAttribute(GAME_SCORE_CONSTANT));

            if (attempts == 0) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute(CREDITS_CONSTANT, --credits);
                message = "Sorry, the word was: [ " + session.getAttribute(WORD_TO_GUESS_CONSTANT) + " ]";
                request.getSession().setAttribute(MESSAGE_CONSTANT, message);
                request.getSession().setAttribute(ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT, startAttempts);
                request.getSession().setAttribute(WORD_TO_GUESS_CONSTANT, randomWord.selectRandomWord());
            }

            if (credits == 0) {
                message = "Game over!";
                request.getSession().setAttribute(MESSAGE_CONSTANT, message);
                request.getSession().setAttribute(GAME_SCORE_CONSTANT, gameScore);

                //   SAVE SCORE
                score.setGameScore(gameScore);
                score.setName(name);
                score.setSelectedLevelName(lvl);
                scoreSavingService.saveScore(score);

                log(GameController.class, "Final score: " + session.getAttribute(GAME_SCORE_CONSTANT));
            }

        } else {
            String message = "Correct! Guess another word!";
            wordToGuess = randomWord.selectRandomWord();
            gameDTO.setWord(wordToGuess);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(MESSAGE_CONSTANT, message);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(WORD_TO_GUESS_CONSTANT, wordToGuess);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT, startAttempts);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(GAME_SCORE_CONSTANT, gameScore + finalScorePerWord);
            log(GameController.class, "Current score 2: " + session.getAttribute(GAME_SCORE_CONSTANT));

        }
        request.getSession().setAttribute(GUESSED_WORD_CONSTANT, guess);
        request.getSession().setAttribute(RESULT_CONSTANT, result);

        log(GameController.class, "Attempts are now: " + session.getAttribute(ATTEMPTS_CONSTANT));

        return "redirect:/index";
    }

    //  BUTTONS

    @PostMapping(value = "/save")
    public String giveUpAndSaveScore(final HttpSession session,
                                     final HttpServletRequest request,
                                     @ModelAttribute("score") Score score) {
        score.setGameScore((Integer) session.getAttribute(GAME_SCORE_CONSTANT));
        score.setName((String) session.getAttribute(NAME_CONSTANT));
        score.setSelectedLevelName((String) session.getAttribute(SELECTED_LEVEL_CONSTANT));
        scoreSavingService.saveScore(score);
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/scores")
    public String seeScores(final HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        List<Score> scoreList = scoreSavingService.getScore(5, 1);
        model.addAttribute("score", scoreList);
        return "scores";
    }

    //  CLOSE SESSION

    @PostMapping(value = "/destroy")
    public String restartGame(final HttpServletRequest request) {


        log(GameController.class, " Session closing. Removing the data.");
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        return "redirect:/index";
    }


    //  EXCEPTION HANDLERS

    @ExceptionHandler(value = ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public String handleArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(final Model model) {

        String text = "ERROR: Could not check empty <<guess>>.";
        model.addAttribute("text", text);
        return "ExceptionPage";
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(value = NullPointerException.class)
    public String handleNullPointerException(final Model model) {

        String text = "ERROR: Cannot compare words because <<word to guess>> is null";
        model.addAttribute("text", text);
        return "ExceptionPage";
    }


}
```

## Thymeleaf template for index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>5Letters</title>
    <link th:href="@{/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-sm">
        <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
            <!--    HEADER  -->
            <img src="https://marisabel.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/avatar-e1606738130828-150x150.png"
                style="margin-top:2vh;">
            <h1 style="margin-top:1vh; color:hotpink;"><b>5Letter Word Game</b></h1>
            <h5>AKA: Lingo.</h5>
            <hr>
        </div>

        <form method="get" th:action="@{/scores}">
            <input type="submit" value="scores" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>


        <!--        Set Up Game Form    -->

        <div class="col-xs-12" align="center" th:hidden="${credits} != null">
                <form th:action="@{/loadgame}" th:object="${gameDTO}" method="post">
                    <p>
                        <select class="form-group" th:field="*{lvlName}" id="dropDownList">
                            <option th:each="lvl : ${lvlName}" th:text="${lvl.lvlName}" th:value="${lvl.lvlName}">
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                    <p><input type="text" class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2" id="name" th:field="*{playerName}"
                            th:placeholder="name" th:value="anonymous" /></p>
                    <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('playerName')}" th:errors="*{playerName}">
                    </p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="start" class="btn btn-primary" /></p>
                </form>
                <p></p>
        </div>


        <!-- This whole session will load after name and level are chosen. Credits will be set to 3, triggering them to unhide -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" align="center" th:hidden="${credits} == null">
                <!--  game information : always show after game setup  -->
                    <h3 th:text="'Hello ' + ${name} + '!'"></h3>
                    <h3 th:text="'Level: '+ ${levelSelected}"></h3>
                    <h2 th:text="'Credits : '+ ${credits} + ' | Score: '+ ${gameScore}"></h2>
                    <h2 th:text="${attempt} + ' / ' + ${attemptStart}"></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6" align="center">
                <p>
                    <!--   Result messages and word after guessing   -->
                <h4 th:text="${message}"></h4>
                <h2 id="result" th:text="${result}" th:hidden="${credits} == 0"></h2>
                <!--        GUESS FORM -->
                <form th:action="@{/guess}" th:object="${gameDTO}" method="post" th:hidden="${credits} == null">
                    <input id="guessField" type="text" th:field="*{guess}" placeholder="5letters" />
                    <p></p>
                    <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('guess')}" th:errors="*{guess}"></p>
                    <input type="submit" value="guess" th:disabled="${credits} == 0" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </form>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row" style="margin-top:10vh;">
            <div class="row justify-content-center" th:hidden="${credits} == null">
                <div class="col col-lg-2 align-items-center">
                    <!-- Destroy session data and go to index -->
                    <form method="post" th:action="@{/destroy}">
                        <input type="submit" value="play again" class="btn btn-danger" />
                    </form>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-auto align-items-center" width="50%">
                    <!-- Display last typed word -->
                    <h4 th:text="'Your guess was:'" th:hidden="${attempt} == ${attemptStart}"></h4>
                    <h2 id="guess" th:text="${guess}" th:hidden="${attempt} == ${attemptStart}"></h2>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-lg-2 align-items-center">
                    <!-- Stops the game if you are bored. Usually needed with EASY mode. -->
                    <form method="post" th:action="@{/save}">
                        <input type="submit" value="i'm tired" class="btn btn-danger" />
                        <p></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I moved the content I was hiding to its own page. It loads the page, but the content remains hidden. Even after taking a break I am still unable to find what is wrong. Specially when it works 100% without validation.